# Android rxjava toList() not returning data

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-android

I have an `Observable` getting data from a `String` array. Each string is an id so i want to query my database table with that array and get an object. Finally i want to add the objects found in a list and return it in the `subscribe()` .Above i have the code i try to do it

```
val temp = Observable.from(plan.components)
            .flatMap {
                id -> subscriptionRepository.getComponentByUuid(id)
                    .filter { component -> !component.enabled }
            }
            .map { component -> component }
            .toList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe ({ list -> TNLog.d("List size is: "+list.size)})

    unsubscribeOnUnbindView(temp)
```

Problem is that even though the code reaches the .map and can see the objects are correct, after the `.toList()` nothing is called. It seems like the `onComplete` is never called so `.subscribe()` doesn't either. How should i fix this issue?

Comment: What is this `subscriptionRepository`? Android databases, for some reason, decided to act as infinite sources, thus they won't complete, so `toList` can't either.

Comment: yeah its actually making a query to my local db through my repository class. So if it is acting as an infite loop how shall i handle it?

Comment: If there is only one component per uuid returned, make that API return `Single` or add `take(1)` after the repository call.

Comment: If i add take(1) then i get a list of size 1 which is not correct

Comment: Then see if you can make your database return `Single<List<componenttype>>` so that the call ends, then use `flattenAsObservable` before filtering.

Comment: What if i cannot do that? Do u think there is another way?

Comment: I'm not experienced in Android databases, but so far, this type of issue could be resolved some way. Otherwise, as a last resort, you could use `timeout`.

Comment: Please post the code of `getComponentByUuid` method

Comment: Your `component -> !component.enabled` code says that you are looking for only disabled components. Is it right? Because if there is no disabled components then there would be nothing to subscribe for.

Answer (score 1):

toList() required onComplete to know when to return. Just call onComplete on your source.